# Apache load balancer And JBoss

Tags: apache, jboss, load-balancing

I am using apache load balancer 2.1 with JBOSS where I have configured 10 jboss nodes to be managed by apache load balancer. Is there any console available in apache load balancer to manage all these nodes and see how many users are handled by each of these nodes when there is some load on the environment?

Comment: What are you using: mod_proxy, mod_jk, something else? Which JBoss version?

Comment: I am using mod_jk and JBoss 5.1 GA

Answer (score 1):

There is a JKManager console. It is not something mind blowing, but is quite useful.

See:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html
- http://www.gesea.de/en/techdocs/admin/tomcat/JKManager-Apache-mod_jk-loadbalancer-status-monitor.htm